# How do I halt Junit from inside eclipse?

Tags: junit, eclipse-plugin

I'm running helium eclipse on Fedora 15 (x86_64).
When I run JUnit to run the tests for a class, there's no button to stop execution.
One of my tests is out of control. Eventually GC fails and eclipse hangs.
I'd like to take it out of its misery long before that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set breakpoint in your code.
2. Right-click the Test file and select the Debug As -> JUnit Test

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Debug" perspective (from the Window menu pick "Open Perspective" then "Debug") and you should see an active process running.   Right-click it and select "terminate"

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the console view open. There is a red stop button that can be used to terminate the running instance.